# git add submodule shallow copy

Tags: git

I am adding RestKit to my project like this.

```
git submodule add git://github.com/RestKit/RestKit.git
```

While I may want to have an entire RestKit repository cloned as a separate project, I only want a shallow copy if I am adding it as a library to another project. The cloning process takes too long and the resulting file size becomes too big, if I am performing a complete clone.

Is it possible to add a submodule to to a git project as a shallow copy?

Comment: What do you mean shallow copy? Do you want the actual repo to store just the reference of subrepo? That's exactly what submodule does. Cloning you main repo doesn't download your subrepo by default. You need to provide --recursive flag while cloning.

Comment: That's the behaviour I had expected but the thing is git is downloading the repo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `git submodule add --depth 1 git://github.com/RestKit/RestKit.git`